# set variables instead of having end-user input them from html form

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables

I have attempted to set these variables (to, from and mode), instead of having the user input them.  What step am I missing?

```
var from = (40.750484, -111.811177);
var to = (40.775041, -111.718560);
var mode = driving;

//$('#directions-form').submit(function(e) {
  //$('#error').hide();
  ds.route({
    origin: from,
    destination: to,
    travelMode: mode
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      fitBounds = true;
      dr.setDirections(result);
    }
    else {
      $('#error').text(status).show();
    }
    recalcHeight();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

ds.route(from,to,mode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
var from = new google.maps.LatLng(40.750484, -111.811177);
var to = new google.maps.LatLng(40.775041, -111.718560);
var mode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
```

Travel Mode documentation with more mode examples here...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes